# create UIPopOverController in iPhone (Swift)

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a UIPopOverController for a swift app i'm working on,

previously in obj-c we can get around with having a category like so [UIPopoverController for iPhone by implementing category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610067/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-by-implementing-category)

how do i perform something similar in swift?

appreciate your help.

=====

In the end I just gave up, didnt see the point in spending too much time on trying to create extensions and cursing myself as to why its not working

used https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController

Comment: In Swift categories are called extensions. So, write an extension which does what your Objective-C category did.

Comment: I did, here it is , but no effect extension UIPopoverController{

 
 class func popoversDisabled()->Bool{
  return false
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

```
extension UIPopoverController {
    class var _popoversDisabled : Bool {
    get { return false }}
}
```

to override UIPopover class' _popoverDisabled which seems to work as the idiom error is gone.

Edit: It is working in Xcode 6 beta 4 on iPhone with iOs7.1

Comment: Tried this on xcode beta 6, popover appears but it occupies the entire screen and does not respect the popoverContentSize set for it. still scratching my head